# Allowing JRE 7 to work with firefox

Tags: java, firefox

I keep getting a class not found error when I try to load a java applet on firefox

I've tried multiple things to fix.

Cleared the Java temp files

Deleted all installations of Java and reinstalled the latest.

However even the java test page fails to load :(

Heres the error:

[image]

heres the dump from the test page

```
  Done.Dump thread list ...
Group main,ac=19,agc=3,pri=10
    main,5,alive
    traceMsgQueueThread,5,alive,daemon
    Timer-0,5,alive
    Java Plug-In Pipe Worker Thread (Client-Side),5,alive,daemon
    AWT-Shutdown,5,alive
    AWT-Windows,6,alive,daemon
    AWT-EventQueue-0,6,alive
    SysExecutionTheadCreator,5,alive,daemon
    CacheMemoryCleanUpThread,5,alive,daemon
    Browser Side Object Cleanup Thread,5,alive
    JVM[id=2]-Heartbeat,5,alive,daemon
Group Plugin Thread Group,ac=3,agc=0,pri=10
    AWT-EventQueue-1,6,alive
    TimerQueue,5,alive,daemon
Group http://www.java.com/applet/TestJava/-threadGroup,ac=4,agc=0,pri=4
    Applet 2 LiveConnect Worker Thread,4,alive
    AWT-EventQueue-2,4,alive
    TimerQueue,4,alive,daemon
    ConsoleTraceListener,4,alive,daemon
Group http://www.java.com/jsp_utils/-threadGroup,ac=2,agc=0,pri=4
    Applet 3 LiveConnect Worker Thread,4,alive
    AWT-EventQueue-3,4,alive
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the error is?

Comment: I don't see classnotfound there. which class is not found?

Comment: added a Screenshot of what the java test page is giving me. Strange thou that the Java console detects it's being accessed by the page

Comment: Can be caused because of plugin in firefox. Disable all the plugins and then try again after restart of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this error was cause by firewall disabling ZoneAlarm resolved the issue.